# Angular How to serialize Date in format yyyy-MM-dd in json request

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an object who has a property 'birthDate' of type Date. 
On screen, I should display the birthday in format DD/MM/YYYY. Now I use bootstrap bsDatePicker.
But in the database, it is stored in the format YYYY-MM-DD(type string). So to submit the modification, I should convert the birthday to this format.

Can you tell me how to serialize the Date(DD/MM/YYYY) to the format YYYY-MM-DD in the JSON request?

Do you have any good idea to optimize the conversion without any change in the database?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First you are going to create a function that accepts a string that contains the date. Then convert it. At the end of the function I have some **ternary code** because if you don't add that part, the date could be **2018-4-2** and you want it **2018-04-02**

```
dateFormater(date:string):string{    
   const today = new Date(date);        
   const day = today.getDate()+1; 
   const month = today.getMonth()+1;
   const year = today.getFullYear();

   return year + "-" + (month<10 ? ("0" + month) : month)+ "-" + (day<10 ? ("0" + day) : day);    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a string, you could just extract the relevant data and returning the correct format, needed to be submit in your json. A possible helper function:

```
    formatDate():string{    
        const today = new Date();        

        const day = today.getDate(); 
        const month = today.getMonth()+1; // this will return 0-11 so you will need to add 1 to make it, 1-12
        const year = today.getFullYear();

        return year+"-"+month+"-"+day;    
    }
```

this will return `"2018-10-19"`.

Comment: You code doesn't fully work. It returns 2018-4-23 when I enter 2018-04-24

Comment: Indeed for the month to have it in MM format, you'll need to format that additionally ie. When its less than 10, Do `'0'+month'.

Comment: I just meant to give a simple example on how to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your anwser, this is what i did:

I map the origin object to the request type with reflxion, for the date:

```
if(item[key] instanceof Date) {
  value = this.dataPipe.transform(item[key], 'yyyy-MM-dd').toString();
}else {
  value = item[key].toString();
}
```